# Convert Custom Post Types to Custom Taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy

I'm trying to convert a bunch of posts within a CPT to items within a Custom Taxonomy, where the post titles become the taxonomy names and the post content becomes the taxonomy descriptions. I have the below code ([also here](http://pastebin.com/Ukrmw2Jt)) in a plugin but am not sure where to add my CPT and Tax names. Or if the code will fire properly from within the plugin. Any ideas?

```
/**
 * Create slugs/terms in jjm_author_tax taxonomy for all jjm_authors posts
 *
 */
function make_taxonomy_from_posts($post_type, $taxonomy){
   // Get all posts
   $query_posts = query_posts(array(
                             // ... of the requested type
                             'post_type'=> $post_type,
                             // ... and it supports the taxonomy
                             'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                             // ... without limit
                             'nopaging' => true,
                  ));

  // Reset the main query
  wp_reset_query();

  foreach ($query_posts as $query_post) {
      $post_id = $query_post->ID;
      $raw_title = $query_post->post_title;
      // Generate a slug based on the title.
      // We want to check for auto-draft so we don't create a term for a post with no title
      $slug_title = sanitize_title($raw_title);

      // Do the checks for empty titles
      // If the title is blank, skip it
      if ($slug_title == 'auto-draft' || empty($raw_title)) continue;
      // Get all of the terms associated with the post
      $terms = get_the_terms($post_id, $taxonomy);
      $term_id = 0;

      if (!empty($terms)) {
           $term_id = $terms[0]->term_id;
      }

     if ($term_id > 0) {
          // If the post has a term, update the term
          wp_update_term($term_id, $taxonomy, array(
                                               'description' => $raw_title,
                                               'slug' => $raw_title,
                                               'name' => $raw_title,
                         ));
     } else {
         // Otherwise add a new term
         wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $raw_title, $taxonomy, false);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You shoule **never** user `query_posts()`. Instead use `get_posts()` or create a custom query using the `WP_Query` class.

Comment: Thanks David. This only runs once so maybe using query posts isn't the end of the world. But I'm still not sure where to plug in my CPT and custom tax names.

Comment: This should work just fine. It converts all posts within a post type (without caring if one with the same name existed before). https://gist.github.com/4b163188440a3785d004

Comment: It's always the end of the world to use `query_posts()`. Maybe even the universe...  But anyway, see my answer below and comment on it if you need further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution that worked for me. I added the below code to a page template (page-test.php) and then created a page called "test," loaded the page, and all the CPTS were converted to taxonomies. Not sure if this happened when I created the page or when I loaded it... And then I quickly deleted the page template so I didn't end up with a bunch of duplicates.

```
<?php
    function cpt_to_tax($post_type, $taxonomy) {
    $posts = get_posts(array(
                 'post_type' => $post_type,
                 'posts_per_page' => -1,
            ));
    
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        wp_insert_term($post->post_title, $taxonomy, array(
                'description' => $post->post_content,
            ));
        }
    }

    cpt_to_tax('jjm_authors', 'jjm_author_tax');
?>
```

The solution itself was provide by https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/35470/circuuz, though his post seems to be deleted now. :(

Comment: That's basically the same as my answer, except it users `get_posts()`.

Comment: I tried your answer in functions.php and it wasn't working, not sure why. But, like the above, it might have worked if I had added it to page template. I'd test it but then if it worked I'd have to delete 462 duplicate tags. :(

Comment: My answer doesn't create duplicate tags. Plus, you **must** at the very least take a back up when doing things like this, and really it's better to test it off line - just in case...

Comment: Of course I had a backup, and all of this was happening on a local machine long before launch of the live site. Also, your code had all sorts of syntax errors, which I started fixing but then decided to give the other answer a shot.

Comment: "your code had all sorts of syntax errors" - LOL, I found that I had accidently placed a semi-colon at the end of the wrong line. It was literally a 3 second fix.  Other than that, the code is tested and works 100%. If you don't want to use it, fine, but if you do you don't have to worry about duplicates because my code will not create any.

Answer (score 1):

First we create a new custom query containing all published posts of type `$post_type`, which you pass to the function.  If you don't just want published posts you can pick and choose the status' that you require - [see this part of the WP_Query Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters).

Next we use [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) to loop through the resultant posts and for each check if the post name exists as a term within $taxonomy (which you also pass to the function) using [`term_exists()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists), and if not, we add it using [`wp_insert_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term).  Using this means that we only have to pass the name and description, while the slug will be automatically created based on the name.

Finally, just before exiting [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) we reset the global `$post` using [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)

Place this entire code block into **functions.php** in the order that it is on here.  While you can just leave this code to run on every page load (duplicate category names **will not** be created), it's recommended for permormance reasons and you should ensure that you comment the call to `add_action()` when you are done.

```
add_action('init', 'init_make_taxonomy_from_posts');
function init_make_taxonomy_from_posts(){
    make_taxonomy_from_posts('jjm_authors', 'jjm_author_tax');
}

/**
 * Create slugs/terms in jjm_author_tax taxonomy for all jjm_authors posts
 */
function make_taxonomy_from_posts($post_type, $taxonomy){

    /** Grab the relevant posts */
    $args = array(
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'post_type'         => $post_type,
        'posts_per_page'    => -1
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    
    /** Check that some posts were found and loop through them */
    if($my_query->have_posts()) : while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    
            /** Check to see if a term with the same title as the post currently exists in $taxonomy */
            if(!term_exists(get_the_title(), $taxonomy)) :   // It doesn't
            
                /** Add a new term to $taxonomy */
                $args = array(
                    'description'   => get_the_content()
                );
                wp_insert_term(get_the_title(), $taxonomy);
                
            endif;
            
        endwhile;
        
        /** Reset the '$post' global */
        wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;

}
```

---

## Note

This code is tested and **100%** working.

Comment: David, am I replacing @post_type and $taxonomy with my custom post name and taxonomy name throughout? And if I put this in a plugin, will it fire when I activate the plugin? Or does it have to be in a theme function file?

Comment: No, call the function using the - `make_taxonomy_from_posts('jjm_authors', 'jjm_author_tax');`.  I'll update the answer to include this.  Also, you can fire it in a plugin, but from now I'd recommend placing it in **functions.php**.

Comment: I don't think I'm adding `make_taxonomy_from_posts('jjm_authors', 'jjm_author_tax');` correctly. Does that go on a line by itself AFTER the main function?

Comment: I've updated my answer, specifically on how to call the function. I assumed you'd know to wrap the call in a function and call via a hook. Hope it helps.